# jQuery.bind'ing things loaded with jQuery.load

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-load

When using `jQuery.load` to dynamically load HTML content into a webpage, what is the best way to "rebind" any handlers?

Normally you bind handlers in `jQuery.ready`, but they obviously don't work on newly loaded content. This is for handlers used both outside and inside the loaded content, so just binding them in the `load` success function is not really nice.

Comment: Don't bind any new event handlers. Check out the documentation on [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When subscribing to those handlers you could use the [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function which allows you to subscribe to even non existing yet DOM elements and when they are added the subscription will be done. The `.on` function was introduced in jQuery 1.7. If you are using an older version you could use the [`.delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) function to achieve the same effect which was introduced in jQuery 1.4.2. And if you are using an even older version you could use the [`.live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) method.

Here's an example of how you could subscribe to the click event of some element (existing or not yet existing that will be added in the future):

```
$('#someParentElement').on('click', '#someElement', function() {

});
```

Comment: small addendum: you'll get better performance if, instead of calling this on `$(document)`, you use the nearest non-dynamic parent.

Answer (score 3):

You need to delegate events for the new content to a static parent element, for example:

```
$("#myDiv").load(myUrl);

$("#myDiv").on('click', '#myElement', function() {
    // do stuff when #myElement (which was part of the HTML 
    // returned in the load() call) is clicked.
})
```

This assumes you're using jQuery 1.7+, if not, use `delegate()`:

```
$("#myDiv").delegate('#myElement', 'click', function() {
    // do stuff when #myElement (which was part of the HTML 
    // returned in the load() call) is clicked.
})
```